# LaTeX symbol for the Kulkarni-Nomizu product

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I would like to know how to type the symbol of [Kulkarni-Nomizu product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulkarni%E2%80%93Nomizu_product) in LaTeX:

[image: Kulkarni-Nomizu product]

I tried to use [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but it does not give me anything.

Comment: It is `\owedge` in the `stmaryrd` fonts.

Comment: @AndrewSwann You should post another answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can combine `\bigcirc` with `\wedge`.

Of course, you can also create and use a new command. The result is, obviously, the same with or without the new command.

*Edit:*

However, with `\mspace` the symbol becomes misaligned when used in `\scriptstyle` or - worse - in `\scriptscriptstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

% Of course, you can create...
\newcommand{\KN}{\mathbin{\bigcirc\mspace{-15mu}\wedge\mspace{3mu}}}

\begin{document}
\[
h \mathbin{\bigcirc\mspace{-15mu}\wedge\mspace{3mu}} k
\]
% ... and use a new command:
\[
h \KN k
\]
\[
x_{h \KN k}
\]
\[
y_{x_{h \KN k}}
\]
\end{document}
```

See the output:

[image]

Comment: It should be `\mathbin`.

Comment: @egreg Corrected, I've also added a little space at the end, otherwise the `k` was too close to the symbol!

Comment: Yes: my measurement says that `\wedge` is 12mu wide, so if you back up by 15mu, you have to compensate with 3mu, which is what `\,` does in math mode; however, I'd use explicitly `\mspace{3mu}` for consistency.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Thank you for editing!

Answer (score 10):

A solution with `\ooalign`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\owedge{\mathpalette\@owedge\relax}
\newcommand*\@owedge[1]{%
  \mathbin{%
    \ooalign{%
      $#1\m@th\bigcirc$\cr
      \hidewidth$#1\m@th\wedge$\hidewidth\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$h \owedge k_{h \owedge k_{h \owedge k}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Henri. But I can only accept one answer.

Comment: @Paul It's better if you accept Henri's solution, my symbol messes up when used in `\scriptstyle` or - worse - in `\scriptscriptstyle`. See the edited version of my answer.